# Pushing off a Hefsek Tahara

Tags: mikvah-ritual-bath, niddah, shulchan-aruch

The Rama in [Yoreh Deah 197:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.197.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes that in some places the practice is that a woman who can go to mikva on Thursday night (or earlier) may not choose to go on Friday night without a valid reason.

Would the same prohibition apply to pushing off a Hefsek Tahara from Thursday to Friday which would cause her to only go on Friday night instead of Thursday night?

I would say that it would also be forbidden but I haven't seen anyone discuss this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Pischei Teshuva 197:3 seems to say that for no reason it would be assur.

> אפשר לה לטבול. עי' בתשו' נודע ביהודה תניינא חלק יו"ד סוף סי' קל" באשה שהיה זמנה ללבוש לבנים ביום ה' ונתאחרה לבא מן השוק שסבורה שעוד היום גדול ובין כך נתאחרה עד בה"ש והוצרכה ללבוש לבנים ביום המחרת ועי"ז חל טבילתה בליל שבת נחשבת שוגגת ומותרת לטבול ליל שבת ע"ש

The Chochmas Adam 118:8 seems to say that it would be permitted

> אבל אם היה באפשר לה לטבול מקודם וברצונה עכבה או אחר לידה שדרך הנשים להמתין כמה שבועות מחמת חולשת' אעפ"י שלא ראו דם או שלא היה בעלה בעיר ובא בע"ש בזה יש מקומות נוהגין להחמיר שלא לטבול בליל שבת דנראה כמתקן (כדאיתא בח"א בהל' שבת כלל מ"ד) ובמקום שאין מנהג ידוע יש להקל אפילו כשכבר ספרה ז"נ כבר כמה ימים אבל כשכלו ז"נ שלה בשבת לכ"ע מותרת:

The [Avnei Nezer Y”D 247](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1345&st=&pgnum=258) clearly says it’s permitted